# Copy behavior of UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Is it possible to copy behavior of `UITabBarController` with the code bellow?

What I am trying to do is to have a "drawer menu" to work as a `UITabBarController`. Each time you press any of the menu items the selected VC for that menu item will become the new root `VC` and the navigation stack will reset making that `VC` becoming the 1st `VC` in stack.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let AccountVc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AccountVc")
        let navigationController = self.view.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

        //Remove both login scene and menu scene
        self.presentingViewController!.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false) { () -> Void in
            navigationController.setViewControllers([AccountVc], animated: false)
        }
    })
```

The code above works, in this case it removes the `MenuVC` together with the `loginVC` and then resets the navigation setting `AccountVC` to be the new root.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: You are calling `storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AccountVc")` each time you do this. This means you are recreating the same view controllers over and over. Do it once and save them somewhere. I am also curious about what would happen if you did not dismiss the presenting view controller.

Comment: @ryantxr I dont understand what you mean. Can I create them and save them without adding them to the navigation stack? If I dont call dismiss in the code above both the modal VC's will remain on top of the new root VC

Comment: Yes, you can create them and save them somewhere without adding them to anything. For example, you could save them in AppDelegate or as a static array or dictionary in some class.